# BigQuery UDF in Python or only in JavaScript

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I have been looking into how to write a UDF in BigQuery and found this syntax:

```
CREATE  { TEMPORARY | TEMP }  FUNCTION
function_name ([named_parameter[, ...]])
[RETURNS data_type]
{ [LANGUAGE language AS """body"""] | [AS (function_definition)] };
```

In [the document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) I found, there is no clear mention of what languages are supported. In the examples given in the page, it only talks about "js" and I can't find any other language examples so I presume it only supports JavaScript but I am wondering whether anyone knows for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From that same page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#supported-external-udf-languages):

## Supported external UDF languages

> External UDFs support code written in JavaScript, which you specify using `js` as the `LANGUAGE`.

You can't use languages other than JavaScript.

Comment: Only JS. But also SQL!

Comment: ..and C/Rust ;-) https://medium.com/@hoffa/bigquery-beyond-sql-and-js-running-c-and-rust-code-at-scale-33021763ee1f