# How to apply Python function to BigQuery columns without loading them?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery dataset with roughly half a million rows:

[image]

**I would like to apply a Python function to two of the columns without loading them - is this possible?**

Ideally, result should be in a new column. The function is not easily translatable to SQL, for a concrete example, see below.

---

Why do I want this?

I would like to find out what country the coordinate pair in each row (`latsE7` and `lonsE7`) is in. This is how I currently do it:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
```

Load GeoPandas map (low resolution but good enough):

```
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
```

Function to find country given coordinate, the function I'd like to apply within BigQuery:

```
def country_finder(lat, lon):
    try:
        res =  world[world.geometry.apply(lambda row: row.contains(Point(lon, lat)))].name.iloc[0]
    except IndexError:
        res = "UNCLEAR" # point isn't in any country (i.e. Ocean)
    return res
```

Apply this function and get a list as a result after loading `latsE7` and `lonsE7` columns from BigQuery to lists:

```
countrylist = [country_finder(latE7/1e7, lonE7/1e7)
               for latE7, lonE7 in tqdm(zip(latsE7, lonsE7),total=len(latsE7))]
```

The problem is that this takes very long, as I can see from the `tqdm` progress bar. I could wait for it and then upload to BigQuery, but I hope there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd poke at the statement that this isn't easily translatable to SQL.  You appear to be describing a geospatial JOIN between your data table and a table that has country geometries, unless I'm missing something.

Take a look at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/geospatial-data for more details about working with geospatial data in BigQuery.  Given your use of `Contains()` from geopandas I'd point you towards [`ST_CONTAINS`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_contains) in particular.

Comment: Given that what I ask for [does not seem possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900395/bigquery-udf-in-python-or-only-in-javascript), I accept this answer.

Comment: The JOIN should also be much faster than per-row function, as BigQuery optimizes such geospatial JOIN.