# BigQuery - Python UDF

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is it now possible to define Python UDFs in BigQuery ? If not is it on the roadmap for soon ?

The last ticket saying that only JavaScript can be used is from 2018 [1].

[1] [BigQuery UDF in Python or only in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900395/bigquery-udf-in-python-or-only-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it’s not possible, only `SQL` and `JavaScript` are supported [natively](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) in `BigQuery`.

But a [feature](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/extending-bigquery-functions) added recently, allows using an udf based on a `Cloud Function` or `Cloud Run` service (Remote Functions).

It give more flexibility and allows using an udf with your preferred language.

Comment: Looks good being able to use `Cloud Function` this way. Any UDAF integration planned as well ?

Comment: There is plans to better integer python in BigQuery directly, with our without remote functions, it will be transparent for you. I have no ETA.

Comment: Does anyone know if Python is better supported by Snowflake, Redshift, Synapse ?